# Select mysql in PHP with 2 vars

Tags: php, mysql

How i can make this whitout php notice error:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '$id' or name = '$name');
```

And how i can do one search in many tables at once.

Thank you

Comment: To search many tables, you can make a bunch of queries and echo them all out. And what do you mean by "whitout php notice error"? That's not an error. Don't forget to do your `mysql_real_escape_string()` too.

Comment: Do you want to know how to search in multiple tables or are you asking about an error you have?

Comment: @Ken: I'd assume it produces a notice when `$_GET['id']` or `$_POST['name']` is not yet defined.

Comment: You're missing a closing `"` on the `$sql` line.

Comment: @animuson Why is he calling them if they aren't defined?

Comment: @Ken: No idea, poor programming? But those are the only two things which could produce notice errors.

Comment: The missing `"` on the line wouldn't cause a notice error! I think that's a typo.

Comment: @BenRowe I didn't mean to imply that it would. I was simply pointing out that it was missing. Also, the asker maybe not actually intend to specify `E_NOTICE`.

Comment: Yes, E_NOTICE. The closing " it was a typing error. Ok, i go to explain better, i have a search input forn "$name" and id for select single register by <a href=bla bla>. Poor programing? may be but is the unique way that i know for optimice, i'm beginner prog.

Answer (score 0):

Your query string is incomplete. You need a closing double quote at the end.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '$id' or name = '$name'");
                   ^                                                      ^
```

To search many tables at once, add more tables separated by a comma.

```
"SELECT table1.field, table2.field FROM table1, table2"
```

Comment: This answers parts of the question I believe he's trying to ask. +1

Comment: Thanks you very much for yours answers. The first question is perfect, but "Search for where unicorns live...;-) still in my mind :). Ok, I mean this:I would like to do a search in many tables with a 
`
   <input type="text" name="search" />

   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars,people,cities WHERE 
   cars.reg= '$search' || people.phone = '$search' || city.address = '$search'");
`
Is it possible to do that? any suggestions for that a DB search with PHP?

Thanks a lot

Comment: It should work. Just make sure you escape your input to prevent SQL injection. Also, I believe the correct syntax in MySQL for or is "OR", not "||".

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null;

if($id !== null || $name !== null) {
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '$id' or name = '$name'");
}
```